# Python - Unable to locate an element by class_name but able to locate by XPATH

Tags: selenium, pytest

I'm trying to locate an element by `class_name` but i'm getting an error "no such element"
When i'm trying to locate the same element by `XPATH` it works

Why it fails to locate the element by his class_name?

this are the 2 locators that i tried:
1: `txt_company_name = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'crm-entity-widget-content-input crm-entity-widget-content-search-input')`

2: `txt_company_name = (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="crm-entity-widget-content-input crm-entity-widget-content-search-input"]')`

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Company name, phone or email" class="crm-entity-widget-content-input crm-entity-widget-content-search-input" autocomplete="nope">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `CLASS_NAME` with spaces do not work in Selenium.

Basically, if you see a class name like this in HTML:

```
crm-entity-widget-content-input crm-entity-widget-content-search-input
```

what it means is, that it is combination of this class `crm-entity-widget-content-input` and `crm-entity-widget-content-search-input`

so you will either have to use the below `CSS_SELECTOR`

```
input.crm-entity-widget-content-input
```

or

```
input.crm-entity-widget-content-search-input
```

or even the below should work, provided it is unique in HTMLDOM:

```
.crm-entity-widget-content-input.crm-entity-widget-content-search-input
```

basically, we use `.` to represent a class in CSS, so you can remove the space and put a `.` and also in the starting and that should help you find the right CSS.

or the XPath that you've should suffice. However, CSS has more precedence than XPath.

Comment: ``'[class="crm-entity-widget-content-input crm-entity-widget-content-search-input"]'`` with the space would also be valid CSS Selector to represent an element with that exact class.

Comment: @Michael Mintz: I have mentioned the same.